# Precedence of Ruby regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am reviewing regular expressions and cannot understand why a regular expression won't match a given string, specifically:

```
regex = /(ab*)+(bc)?/ 
mystring  = "abbc"
```

The match matches `"abb"` but leaves the `c` off. I tested this using Rubular and in IRB and don't understand why the regex doesn't match the entire string. I thought that `(ab*)+` would match `"ab"` and then `(bc)?` would match `"bc"`.

Am I missing something in terms of precedence for regular expression operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex with parenthesis assumes you have two matches in your string.

The first one is `abb` because `(ab*)` means `a` and zero or more `b`. You have two `b`, so the match is `abb`. Then you have only `c` in your string, so it doesn't match the second condition which is `bc`.

Comment: Ah, so assuming a,b,c are the only characters in a language, the (bc)? seems to me like it will never match on anything then. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, the regex looks weird.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions try to match the first part of the regular expression as much as possible by default, and they do *not* backtrack to try to make larger sections match if they don't have to. Since you make `(bc)` optional, the `(ab*)` can match as much as it wants (the non-zero repetition after it doesn't have much to do) and doesn't try backtracking to try other matching alternatives.

If you want the whole string to be matched (which will force some backtracking in this case) make sure you anchor both ends of the string:

```
regex = /^(ab*)+(bc)?$/
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to match the entire string with anchors

Comment: @jskoeh9 I thought that was the _real_ question behind the question you were asking…